# Differentiation, an issue with an exercise

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm currently working on an exercise that involves quite a few fractional exponents. This is it: $$y = \frac {(x^4 + a)^\frac {1}{3}} {(x^3 + a)^ \frac {1}{2}} $$

I take the multiplication route by doing:

$$(x^4 + a)^ \frac{1}{3}(x^3 + a) ^ \frac {-1}{2} $$

I eventually get $$(x^4 + a)^\frac {1}{3} \frac{-3}{2}x^2(x^3 + a)^ \frac{-3}{2} + (x^3 + a)^ \frac{-1}{2}\frac{4}{3}x^3(x^4 + a)^\frac{-2}{3}$$

This is what I can't get past at the moment. I'm not sure of the next step I should take to ensure I get the correct answer. Any help on this is much appreciated as always! There may be some formatting issues with the negative fractional exponents as they do look a little odd.

Comment: In this kind of problem, the Quotient Rule is often easier to handle. All the more so because we are often interested in where the derivative is positive, negative, $0$, and then the *numerator* obtained from the quotient rule usually tells us all we need to know. As things stand, your answer is correct, but perhaps not in optimal form for further processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to know what simplify means. Let's accentuate the positive.

Multiply top and (missing) bottom by $6(x^3+a)^{3/2}(x^4+a)^{2/3}$. The $6$ in front is to get rid of fractions.

That makes the denominator reasonably simple. The numerator becomes, I think
$$-9x^2(x^4+a)+ 8x^3(x^3+a).$$
This can be "simplified," to $8x^3 a-9x^2 a-x^6$. So one simplified form is
$$\frac{8x^3 a-9x^2 a-x^6}{6(x^3+a)^{3/2}(x^4+a)^{2/3}}.$$

**Remark:** The form that comes out **naturally** from the logarithmic differentiation described by Ron Gordon is I think nicer. The niceness of it should be interpreted as a message that says it is the right way to do it.

Comment: I see. It sounds like I should take the time to learn logarithmic differentiation then. I'm sure I will get to it in this book. The answer provided in the back of the book is:
Not sure if MathJaX can be implemented in comments.

Comment: @Blake_B: Your comment above did not supply the book's answer. And yes, you can use LateX in comments, somewhat more limited but usable.

Comment: The books answer is: $$\frac{3}{2}x^2[\frac{8}{9}x(x^3 + a) - (x^4 + a)] \over (x^4 + a)^ \frac{2}{3}(x^3 + a)^ \frac{3}{2}$$

Comment: That is the same answer as the one I had at an earlier stage in my answr, except with a common factor $x^2$ brought out in front. Also, the $6$ I have in the denominator is instead a factor of $\frac{1}{6}$ in the numerator. Also, a $\frac{3}{2}$ has been brought out as a common factor, for no good reason. (The arithmetic is correct, but there are unnecessary fractions that make things look more complicated than they are.)

Answer (score 1):

Logarithmic differentiation is useful here.

$$\log{y} = \frac13 \log{(x^4+a)} - \frac12 \log{(x^3+a)}$$

Then

$$\frac{y'}{y} = \frac13 \frac{4 x^3}{x^4+a} - \frac12 \frac{3 x^2}{x^3+a}$$

Multiply by the original $y$ and you are done.

Comment: Thanks Ron. I believe your answer to be correct, however, I haven't reached logarithmic differentiation yet. If there is another way of simplifying this answer aside from logarithmic differentiation I would greatly appreciate seeing how that is done.